# Dividing dicionary values by other list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, biopython

I want to calculate the probabilty of values I have in a dictionary by dividing them with a list.
this is the dict:

```
PPM = {'A': [1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0], 'T': [3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0],
       'C': [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4], 'G': [1, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]}
```

and I want to divide each number with the length of this list:

```
sequences = ["GAGGTAAACTCTG", "TCCGTAAGTTTTC", "CAGGTTGGAACTC", "ACAGTCAGTTCAC",
         "TAGGTCATTACAG", "TAGGTACTGATGC"]
```

I tried to do a for loop that goes something like that:

```
PPM = {}
for k in PFM:
PPM[k]= [((x[i]/len(sequences)) == k for x in PFM) for i in range(len(PFM))]
```

but the results is this:

```
{'A': [<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022407181580>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022407181820>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022407181F90>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022407181970>], 'T': [<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022407181F20>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224071819E0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224071816D0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224071817B0>], 'G': [<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224060FEF20>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224060FEB30>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224060FE9E0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224060FEF90>], 'C': [<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224060FE820>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x000002240717C190>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x000002240717CE40>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x000002240717CEB0>]}
```

Im new to python so I don't really understand what wrong with what I did.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Comment: What is PFM? 

[Padding SO character limit.]

Comment: Your PPM is first a dict() and then an empty dict()

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly (and please correct me / clarify if this isn't what you mean), you could use the following dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {k: [i/len(sequences) for i in v] for k, v in PPM.items()}

{'A': [0.16666666666666666,
       0.6666666666666666,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.0,
       0.5,
       0.6666666666666666,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.5,
       0.0,
       0.3333333333333333,
       0.0],
 'C': [0.16666666666666666,
       0.3333333333333333,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.0,
       0.3333333333333333,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.6666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.6666666666666666],
 'G': [0.16666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.6666666666666666,
       1.0,
       0.0,
       0.0,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.5,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.0,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.3333333333333333],
 'T': [0.5,
       0.0,
       0.0,
       0.0,
       1.0,
       0.16666666666666666,
       0.0,
       0.3333333333333333,
       0.5,
       0.5,
       0.3333333333333333,
       0.5,
       0.0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if I got exactly what you need, but if you want to update your dictionary so that each element in the dictionary's lists is divided with the length of the sequences list, you can try:

```
for key, value in PPM.items():
    value = [
        number/len(sequences)
        for number in value
        if sequences
    ]
    PPM.update({key:value})
```

If you don't want to update your original dictionary, you can create similarly a new one:

```
p = {
    key: [
            number/len(sequences) 
            for number in value 
            if sequences
        ]
    for key, value in PPM.items() 
}
```